# Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined error message trying to use jquery with ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I keep getting the following error message: 
Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

I've included the jquery ui js file like so:

```
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
         <head runat="server">
         <title>jquery Test Page</title>
          <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

         <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11-min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

         <script>
              $(function () {
              $('#startdate').datepick({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
              });        
         </script>
         </head>
        <body>
           <form id="form1" runat="server">
             jquery date picker test: <asp:TextBox ID="startdate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

I think the problem is with the URL.CONTENT include - the compiler is complaining that it can't find the js files in the Url.Content line.  But i can see them in my solution folder - they are definitely included in the Scripts folder.  I think its my quotes but I can't figure out what it is. I've tried changing the actual file name inside the Url.Contents to have single quotes instead of double quotes.  But that didn't resolve the problem. I've also tried no quotes.

Perhaps you can see what I'm missing - i'm sure its something simple that i'm overlooking.

Comment: You script missing `jQuery library`.. Include jQuery library before `jQuery UI`

Comment: Does it work if you hard-code the paths in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things I see:

1. **Bad link?**  Your jQuery UI link may be wrong.  Usually the name of the file in ASP.NET MVC initial setup project (and I'm assuming that's what you are using here for a basis) is jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js.  May need to change the dash to a dot after "11".  But without seeing your setup in VS I cannot be sure.
2. **Wrong UI method.** "datepick" isn't a valid method in the jQuery UI.  If you are trying to instatiate a datepicker you should use **datepicker** instead.
3. **ASP.NET controls.** If this is an MVC project (and once again I assume it is) you shouldn't be using the asp:TextBox.  Use an input tag instead.

Comment: i double checked the paths.. they seem correct.  But when i do F12 and click on the Script tab, then click on the drop down menu to see which files i can view, i see "default.asp" but then "jquery-1.4.1.js')".  Notice the ') in the file name?  What do you think is causing that?

Comment: Hmmm....not sure. Only thing I can think of is the path in the markup is wrong?  What browser and tools are you using?  Also, do you see the jQuery source when you select it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery, not just jQuery UI.

Comment: I've modified my original post to show what my code looks like now... I'm still getting the same error messsage

Comment: after making that code change, now i do see an error message in my source code.  The Url.content is underlined in green and the compiler is saying "File '@Url.Content(' was not found.  Maybe my quotes are incorrect?